# Moving Jib configuration of one module into a new module, to refactor multi-module gradle project

Tags: java, gradle, multi-module, jib

I have a multi-module gradle project and one of the modules is a webapp. I added Jib configuration within the webapp build.gradle file to generate the container images.
Similarly I have a few modules for command-line applications and I use Jib jar config to create container images.

I want to move the Jib specific configuration in new modules to unclutter the webapp/app build.gradle files and want achieve this by creating new modules (say ':container:tomcat', ':container:app1') and setting up a task (or something) to set Jib config here for webapp/app project. I am not sure what gradle apis I need to call to achive the same?
I know I can access the webapp/app module from new module build.gradle file but not sure how to set the Jib configuration there.

Can someone please suggest how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being on Gradle, there are many ways to achieve whatever you want. One idea of mine is to create a new module (say, `jibconf`) for the following `build.gradle`.

```
['jib', 'jibDockerBuild', 'jibBuildTar'].each { jibTaskName ->
  task "${jibTaskName}Webapp" {
    doFirst {
      project(':webapp').jib {
        to.image = 'jib-webapp'
        // and more ....
      }
    }
    finalizedBy ":webapp:$jibTaskName"
  }

  task "${jibTaskName}App" {
    doFirst {
      project(':app').jib {
        to.image = 'jib-app'
        // and more ...
      }
    }
    finalizedBy ":app:$jibTaskName"
  }
}
```

Then running `./gradelw jibW` or `./gradle jibDBW` at the root builds a webapp image, while `./gradlew jibA` or `./gradlew jibDBA` builds an app image.

Note that it's recommended to register a task than outright creating it, so I'd actually do this:

```
  tasks.register("${jibTaskName}Webapp") { ...
```

Comment: I know this wasn't exactly Jib question and would like to thank you for your prompt answer.